# Problems when redirecting to a page after Paypal payment

Tags: html, flask, redirect, paypal

I am building a website (using python, flask, html, css, js) that requires a Paypal payment in order to input information. I want when a person pays the amount of money (by clicking a Paypal button) to be redirected on this page:

[image: Input word page]

So far so good, I have done this. On my initial page, I have created a working Smart Paypal button (like this one - [smart paypal button example](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client)) which redirects me to the above mentioned page. However, my first problem is: When a person pays with paypal and gets redirected to the page above and then he enters a word and moves to the next page with the results. Now he can click "back" on the browser and enter another word once again. I don't want this to happen. I want a person who has paid to be able to enter a word only once.

My second problem is that, as you can see from the image the link is "/127.0.0.1:5000/word". When a person enters this url it automatically opens without payment. I need this to be somehow locked or unavailable without the required Paypal payment.

Could you guys please suggest to me any ideas how can I overcome these problems?

Comment: You need to implement some kind of sign-in and order management system that allows users to submit only one word per payment.

Comment: @PrestonPHX - Thanks for answering but this website can't have any log-in sign-in implementation. I am looking for a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could generate a unique token/UUID or use the PayPal transaction ID, redirect to a URL with that ID, and only allow one word to be submitted with that ID

Comment: I will try to implement something like that.